# Unable to instantiate external Hive Metastore in Postgres / driver not found in classpath

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, data-science

I am using Cloudera CDH 6.3 with Spark 2.4.4. SparkConf() has config that connects to external Hive Postgres Metastore. Upon running below Scala code

```
sqlc.sql("show databases")
```

...I'm getting an error:

```
unable to instantiate hive metastore
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException of datastore driver ("org.postgresql.Driver") not found in the CLASSPATH. 
Check CLASSPATH specification and the name of the driver.
```

Detailed log is mentioned in error Log. I tried with same Spark config settings shown in below code from pyspark Spark SQL, and got connected to external Hive metastore with no issues. Included build.sbt file at the end. Any leads on how to make this scala snippet connect to external hive metastore is highly appreciated.

What i tried:

> 1. Moved hive-site.cml to spark/conf folder
> 2. Changed permissions of /tmp/hive location to 777 within hdfs
> 3. Move the postgresql-jdbc driver from HIVE_HOME to SPARK_HOME
> 4. Spark-env.sh has Exported SPARK_CLASSPATH to the postgresql-jdbc driver location
> 5. Tried with hiveContext.sql instead of SQLContext.sql as mentioned by commentator. Still no luck.

**Scala code snippet**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().
 setAppName("MQJMSReceiver").
 set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "10000").
 set("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "non-strict").
 set("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").
 set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","hdfs://xxx/user/hive/warehouse").
 set("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://xxx/user/hive/warehouse").
 set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive").
 set("spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes","org.postgresql").
set("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:postgresql://xxx/hive").
 set("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","org.postgresql.Driver").
 set("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","xxx").
 set("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","xxx").
 setMaster("local[*]").
 set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlc.implicits._

sqlc.sql("show databases").show()
```

**Error Log**

```
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName unknown - will be ignored
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL unknown - will be ignored
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName unknown - will be ignored
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword unknown - will be ignored
20/04/16 15:16:50 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
20/04/16 15:16:50 WARN HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Error creating transactional connection factory
javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.mq.SparkMQExample$$anonfun$functionToCreateContext$1.apply(MQReceiverExample.scala:155)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.mq.SparkMQExample$$anonfun$functionToCreateContext$1.apply(MQReceiverExample.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:282)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:240)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.mq.SparkMQExample$$anonfun$functionToCreateContext$1.apply(MQReceiverExample.scala:155)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.mq.SparkMQExample$$anonfun$functionToCreateContext$1.apply(MQReceiverExample.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "BONECP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("org.postgresql.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:259)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:85)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException: The specified datastore driver ("org.postgresql.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:58)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:54)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:238)
    ... 123 more
```

**Build.sbt file**

```
name := "spark-app"
version := "0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4","2.11.7")
val sparkVer = "2.4"

resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

//addSbtPlugin("org.spark-packages" % "sbt-spark-package" % "0.2.3")

//addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")

licenses += "Apache-2.0" -> url("http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "javax.jms" % "jms-api" % "1.1-rev-1",
  "com.ibm.mq" % "com.ibm.mq.allclient" % "9.1.4.0",
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.4",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.4",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.4"
)
```

Comment: Using hiveContext might help to resolve this issue. As importing ```from pyspark.sql import HiveContext```, also there is an example of this for on another platform https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730731/error-creating-transactional-connection-factory-during-running-spark-on-hive-pro

Comment: Hi @furkanayd tried with hiveContext as well. Still no luck. As mentioned in question, pypark is working with no issues. Only the scala code is having issues. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by including postgres library to build.sbt file as dependency

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.12

Pyspark doesnot need explicit addition of dependencies like scala. Hence the same program ran successfully with python spark.sql api.

Error of unable to instantiate hive metastore in the starting was misleading. Had to read complete error log to find out the exact cause. Keeping postgres library in spar/conf folder or setting class path to postgres driver in basrc is of no use.